# Framer motion with react js

Tags: framer-motion

I want to use two useScroll() with specific values each like this

```
const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: boxRef,
    offset: ["0 1", "1.33 1"],
  });
  const scaleProgress = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0.8, 1]);
 
// the second 

const parallaxRef = useRef();
const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: parallaxRef,
    offset: ["0 1", "0 0.5"],
  });
  const height = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [1, 0]);
```

But i get error every time
How to do ?
Thanks